# jquery not cycling through css slideshow

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, slideshow

I have been using (and have slightly adapted) a slideshow from css-tricks.coma.

When I use the following jquery code, it works great (except for IE, where it just stacks the images on top of each other, rather than cycling through):

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#slideshow1 > div:gt(0)").hide();
                setInterval(function() { 
                $('#slideshow1 > div:first')
                    .fadeOut(500)
                    .next()
                    .fadeIn(500)
                    .end()
                    .appendTo('#slideshow1');
                },  750);
        });}, 750);
```

Somebody suggested (as an IE fix) to change the .appendTo line (3rd last in the script above) from 
    .appendTo('#slideshow1')
to
    .appendTo('#slideshow1 > div:first')

This allows IE to cycle through the slideshow, but only once. Moreover, the slideshow also now only cycle once on Safari, Chrome, and Firefox, whereas it was cycling correctly in the original version.

Here are a couple of jsfiddles:

The working version: http://jsfiddle.net/Zcx62/10/
The non-working version: http://jsfiddle.net/Zcx62/20/

```
#slideshow1 {
    margin:0 auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 60px; 
    height: 60px;   
    border: 5px solid #CBCED1}

#slideshow1 > div {
    position: absolute}

<div id="slideshow1">
    <div><img src="Image URL in fiddle"></div>
    <div><img src="Image URL in fiddle"></div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
.appendTo('#slideshow1 > div:first');
```

use this:

```
.insertAfter('#slideshow1 > div:last');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Zcx62/23/

Although you might also be able to solve your IE problems just by using your original code and adding the following CSS:

```
#slideshow1 > div:first-child {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Zcx62/24/

Comment: Thank you so much as the insertAfter command did the trick. I was unable to get your second suggestion to work, however.

Comment: That was a guess; I didn't really have enough information about your original code. Glad the first solution helped. Don't forget to accept answers to your questions to encourage others to help you in the future.